# replace() method of form submitted data returns "TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

So I'm trying to replace any "−" submitted from my Google Form with "-" to be able to process it mathematically(I do parseInt() further down in the excluded code) in my spreadsheet. My way of trying to do it here is probably quite clunky, but I somewhat expected it to work and I can't see why it wont.

```
function myNotification(e) {

  var i;
  var temp = [];
  var ent = [];
  var eventInput = e;
  var vArray = e.values; // just for the sake of it

  for(i = 0; i < 150; i++){

     ent[i] = e.values[i]

    temp[i] = ent[i].replace("−","-"); //TypeError




  }
```

I would truly appreciate any possible help I can receive as I've been trying to figure this out for a while, but my limited understand of js(or coding in general) really makes it hard.

EDIT: I normally don't have .toString() included in the code, but this also gives me the same TypeError as replace()

EDIT2: `var ja = e.values[2].replace("−","-");` gave me "-1" instead of the normal "−1" which is exactly what I want, but I don't want to write down all 150 potential conversions

EDIT3(5): This: [Google Script not properly accepting event input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24411020/google-script-not-properly-accepting-event-input?rq=1) seems very relevant, <strike>but I tried adding the declarations he ended up making to fix the problem, but it doesn't seem to do anything for me. Code updated.</strike>
This worked as long as I made both the variables:

```
var vArray = e.values;
  var arrayLength = e.values.length;
```

EDIT4: As suggested e.values.length in the for loop fixed the issue.
updated code:

```
  var i;
  var temp = [];
  var ent = [];
  var eventInput = e;
  var vArray = e.values;




  for(i = 0; i < e.values.length; i++){

     ent[i] = e.values[i];


    temp[i] = ent[i].replace("−","-");




  }
```

Comment: If there's any issues with my question please just say so and I'll try to fix it.

Comment: I'm sorry @AppuAmruth, I'm not entirely sure what you mean, if you mean what the trigger is then it's on form submissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limit your for loop till the length of array.

```
function myNotification(e) {
   for(i = 0; i < e.values.length; i++){
   ent[i] = e.values[i].toString();
   temp[i] = ent[i].replace("−","-"); 
   }
}
```

Comment: ReferenceError: console is not defined

Comment: its javascript function rt? how come console.log() is undefined.

Comment: it seems like javascript functions are not working in your code

Comment: but yes, the problem seems to be e.values[i], as mentioned above e.values[2] worked

Comment: try for(i = 0; i < e.values.length; i++){} once

Comment: I have no clue why this worked, but it luckily did. I just accept answer, depite it was the comment, yes?